# Ajax not giving response even on Success

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have a simple page

```
$.ajax({
    url: "abc.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  { 'json': JSON.stringify(match) , 'source': source} ,
    success: function(response){
        alert("Alert 1");
    }
});



alert("hello");
location.reload();
```

It always alert as `"hello"`, I also tried `fail:` but couldn't find the proper results.
Please help me in this regard

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **Async**!!!

Comment: @ArunPJohny nightmare for me, getting  contradicting def on each site regarding async

Comment: @user1765876-- whats confusing you about async, be happy to clear any questions up.

Comment: add this to check error =>   error: function(response){
        alert("error");
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as soon as you sent the request, you are reloading the page - without waiting for the response of the ajax request to comeback.

The solution is to do the reload on the ajax request success/complete callback

```
$.ajax({
    url: "abc.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data:  { 'json': JSON.stringify(match) , 'source': source} ,
    success: function(response){
        alert("Alert 1");
    }
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error){
    alert('error:' + status + ':' + error+':'+xhr.responseText)
}).always(function(){
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: still it is showing hello, and once I click Ok on hello alert it reloads the page..

Comment: @user1765876 I've updated the answer with a fail handler... check whether it is getting called

Comment: Bt point is that abc.php saves data into DB and it is saving it ,without any problem,why the response is in error()

Comment: @user1765876 I've updated the error handler again with a more descriptive message can you try it

Comment: the response was error:parsererror:SyntaxError: Unexpected token <:<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'><b>array</b> <i>(size=15)</i>  'FirstName'
There was a big message after it that contain some variables and values I am sending from this page..

Comment: @user1765876 that is the reason, you are saying it is a json response but it is not.... what is the actual response you are expecting?

Comment: @user1765876 change `dataType: 'json'` to `dataType: 'text'` and check

Comment: I have made one echo "Done"; in abc.php so i believe the response should be "Done"

Comment: @user1765876 if the response is `Done` then it is not a valid json respone, so change your dataType as I said in the previous post

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full code, you are not giving time to execute your ajax call abc.php. You are just refreshing the page without waiting for the ajax to response.

From Jquery doc, 
**The first letter in Ajax stands for "asynchronous," meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed.**